# Accessing Simple Feature geometry column for density calculation

Tags: r, r-sf

I work with spatial data and I am used to work with `Spatial*` objects. I recently started using `sf` package and it seems to make life easier in some cases. However I have a trouble when trying to work with raster package. In `kde2d` function I need to provide X and Y of each point which is easy in `sp` package:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(MASS)
library(tibble)
library(raster)

x <- tibble(a = 1:3, lon = 19:21, lat = 19:21)
coordinates(x) <- ~ lon + lat 
proj4string(x) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
density_x <- kde2d(x$lon, x$lat, n = 30, h = 1)
plot(raster(density_x))
```

But then I was trying to achieve the same using `sf` package and an error occurred:

```
y <- st_as_sf(x, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
density_y <- kde2d(y$lon, y$lat, n = 30, h = 1)
plot(raster(density_y))
```

I do not know how to get into geometry column the same way as with `sp` package. I tried workaround, but it looks ugly:

```
y <- st_as_sf(x, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
coords <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(y$geometry))
density_y <- kde2d(coords$X, coords$Y, n = 30, h = 1)
plot(raster(density_y))
```

Is there any other way to achieve that? Maybe you use some better packages than `raster` to deal with density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the "remove" argument to FALSE in `st_as_sf()` will do the trick:

```r
x <- tibble(a = 1:3, lon = 19:21, lat = 19:21)
y <- st_as_sf(x, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326, remove = F)
y

#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 19 ymin: 19 xmax: 21 ymax: 21
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       a   lon   lat         geometry
#>   <int> <int> <int> <simple_feature>
#> 1     1    19    19  <POINT (19 19)>
#> 2     2    20    20  <POINT (20 20)>
#> 3     3    21    21  <POINT (21 21)>

density_y <- kde2d(y$lon, y$lat, n = 30, h = 1)
plot(raster(density_y))
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't think to check there. Thanks for that! However I now have two places storing the same data ;)

Comment: Glad it helped. You can always remove the geometry column, if you don't need it.